# Forums for Discussing 3D Reconstruction from Images

Tags: discussion

While this and other StackExchange sites are extremely useful, as I understand it, they're for specific questions & answers, not discussions.  Some of my questions aren't really well enough evolved to be on here.

Does anyone know of any good forums for discussing 3D reconstruction from images?  I.e., some place where ideas can be tossed around, critiqued, argued, etc.?

Comment: I would say this is the community for such question. You can also try Computer Graphics. There is no forum dedicated to Computational Photography. You might start the tag here.

Answer (score 2):

As Royi says in their comment, the main forum where you originally asked this question is probably the best in the *Stack Exchange* family for the topic of **3D Reconstruction.**

Where it's possibly *not* a good fit is the part where you say *ideas can be tossed around, critiqued, argued*.

The reason is that this side is a Question and Answer site.  Depending on how you posed your post, *tossed around, critiqued, argued* might not be a good fit.

I'd suggest you try by starting with a first question, and let's see if we can massage it into something that's a good fit for the site and that gets you the information you're after.

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear, but I was already aware that tossing around ideas, etc., wouldn't be a good fit. I was looking for suggestions of non-Stack Exchange forums that might be more appropriate for that kind of discussion.